# Can the Installation Monitor from the Win2K Resource kit be used on newer OS's?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, installation, windows-server-2000

Can the utility "Installation Monitor" from the [Windows 2000 Resource Kit Tools for administrative tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927229) be used on newer OS's, specifically, Windows Server 2008 R2.

The main thing I am concerned about is it may error will not track things correctly without letting me know that that it errored due to how Windows has changed between 2000 and today.

If that is not the correct tool to use to monitor what a application is writing to the hard drive and registry, can you recommend me what I should use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a pile of Sysinternals tools that can help with what you're trying to do. You're probably interested in [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), which consolidates the FileMon and RegMon tools into a single utility.

Comment: Yea, that's what I am currently using, I was just hoping there was a better tool that was tailored for installations. ProcMon has a case of "information overload". There is too much clutter you need to filter through to actually find the relevant information.